# Yii CDbCommand returns different value than MySQL clients

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have command:

```
$night_command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
  ->select('COUNT(d1.id)')
  ->from('diary1 as d1')
  ->where('d1.deleted = 0 AND TIME(d1.datetime_created) BETWEEN "04:59:00" AND "17:59:00"');
 $night_command->getText(); // this is query that i copy to client app
 $night_command->queryScalar(); // returns 4
```

`$night_command->getText()` returns query:

```
SELECT COUNT(d1.id)
FROM `diary1` `d1`
WHERE d1.deleted = 0 AND TIME(d1.datetime_created) BETWEEN "04:59:00" AND "17:59:00"
```

When i copy and run this query - i get 25(not 4). Why? Seems like it is problem with comparing time, because without it everything works well. `datetime_created` column has DATETIME type.

Comment: Which one is wrong? The yii result? Could you be using query caching on the db component before your code up there?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in config of `db` component. It has a parameter

```
'initSQLs' => array(
  'SET time_zone = "+10:00"',
),
```

Which add +10(+8 in my case) hours to `DATETIME` column. E.g. if in DB i have value "11.01.2016 13:21:05"(my local timezone is UTC+2), then Yii returns value "11-01-2016 21:21:05"(for UTC+10). So, or comment this parameter or keep in mind, that `DATETIME` and `TIME` columns will have different value in Yii.